# If (X, τ) is an open subspace of (Y, τ1), prove that (X, τ) is locally homeomorphic to (Y, τ1).

Tags: general-topology

Let (X, τ) and (Y, τ1) be topological spaces. A map f : X → Y is said to be a local homeomorphism if each point x ∈ X has an open neighbourhood U such that the restriction of f to U maps U homeomorphically onto an open subspace V of (Y, τ1); that is, if the topology induced on U by induced on V = f(U) by
τ is τ1 is τ3, then f is a homeomorphism of (U, τ2) onto
(V, τ3). The topological space (X, τ) is said to be locally homeomorphic to (Y, τ1) if there exists a local homeomorphism of (X, τ) into (Y, τ1).

Comment: Learn a little MathJax.

Answer (score 1):

Trivial: for each $x \in X$, take $U=X$ and the embedding $i(x)=x$ as the homeomorphism.